# Trying to create drop down from nav bar to login but having problems calling Login method from ASP.NET MVC Account controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a login box from a drop down off my navigation in my ASP.NET MVC app.  I'm using a bootstrap form and trying to call the login action from the Account controller which requires the parameters LoginViewModel and a string for returnUrl but it seems like nothing is happening when I test the login. If I click when the form is empty I see the error function from my Ajax method.  I don't know if I'm passing the parameters correctly or what the problem might be but I just can't figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        $('#btnLogin').click(function(e) {
        var data = {
            Email: $("#username").val(),
            Password: $("#password").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Account/Login/",
            data: `{model: ${JSON.stringify(data)}, returnUrl: ${JSON.stringify("/Home/Index")} }`,
            success:
                function() {
                    $("#LoginDropDown").attr("hidden", true);
                },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there any error on the browser's console?  In the browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Is the `success` callback invoked?  This is a good time to familiarize yourself with the browser's debugging tools, there's a lot of information you can find there.

Comment: The only error message I saw was 500 internal server error but don't know what's causing it, I would imagine it's something to do with the parameters I'm passing to the action.

Comment: That basically means there was an error on the server, which could be anything.  Check the body of the response to see if it has debugging info.  You can potentially get more information by changing the web.config to show more.  You can also catch and handle exceptions in the action method, debug within that method, etc.  But basically you need to find out what the error is before you can meaningfully address it.